# How to change back the perspective after terminating the debugged process in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse by default automatically switches to the Debug perspective when you hit a breakpoint.

However, it is annoying me that it doesn't automatically switch back to the previous perspective (say, Java) when terminating the process.

It just stays in the debug perspective even though there is nothing to debug because nothing is running.

Comment: This is sad. 7 years and still not implemented

Comment: Let's vote for the issue in the bugtracker then. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46336

Answer (score 29):

To complete mark's answer, that option tells Eclipse when to switch to the associated perspective upon program suspension - meaning when a breakpoint is hit, it will switch to Debug perspective.

**Switching back to another perspective after you're done debugging has to be:**

- **manual (mouse click)**
- **manual ("Switch Perspective" shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>F8</kbd>)**
- **automatic**: [Debug Perspective Auto Closer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/debug-perspective-auto-closer), which supplements [bug 46336](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46336). (initially reported by [zim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11067386/zim))

> ### Debug Perspective Auto Closer
>
> Automatically opens previous perspective when debugging ends.
>
> Behaviors: (configurable: `Preferences -> Debug Perspective Auto Closer`)
>
> 1. [default] when all debug launches have terminated, changes to perspective active on first launch
> 2. when any debug launch has terminated, changes to perspective active on that launch

[image: Java perspective]

If you want to avoid it switching to Debug in the first place, you can choose "Never" as the option (introduced in Eclipse 3.2 at the time).

(You can find the given `Preferences` page in `Run/Debug > Perspective`)

[image]

If you want to  switch back in the situation where the debugged program terminates normally (Not when *you* want to stop debugging it yourself), you may hope Eclipse figures out that your program terminates normally and switch to a "default" perspective at that time...

However, there is no notion of "default" perspective, so how would Eclipse knows which one to switch to ? (the "Preferences/Perspectives/Make default" is only for the "Open Perspective" dialog, but that may not be the same perspective than the one you actually want to switch back to after a debug)

[image: Open perspective]

Also, should Eclipse closes the Debug perspective or just changes to a different one ?
What if there is more than one program running -- when one terminates, you might still be interested in debugging the other one, or maybe not.

The point is, the decision about *when* to change perspective (and *what* perspective to change to) is not reasonable for the machine to make -- it requires a person knowing what he wants to do next.

Comment: I agree with everything but "is not reasonable for the machine to make ". Visual Studio does a fine job by returning to the main view when there are no processes left to debug.

Comment: @Joe Ludwig: agreed. Eclipse may be victim of its own complexity, tricking itself into *not* offering this feature.

Comment: @Joe Ludwig: btw, sorry: I did not play at Pirate: I am not so much into MMO... Right now, I play GTAIV (solo) ;)

Comment: I think the appropriate solution would be to switch back to the previous perspective that I was in before the debug perspective, if all debug sessions have ended. As Joe mentioned, Visual Studio, and all other IDEs i've used do this by default.

Comment: Amazing answer, +1. But... do you care to elaborate a bit on "mark's answer"? I think he may have deleted his answer.. was there any relevant info there that you didn't cover?

Comment: @MestreLion No, Mark hasn't deleted his answer. He has changed his name though to IAdapter. Who might have refered to a thread similar to http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/337020/?srch=plugin+switch+perspective#msg_337020. Note: I have restore the missing picture in my answer.

Comment: @VonC: could you please specify that you can find the given *Preferences* page in `Run/Debug > Perspective` ? It can be confused with the `General > Perspective` view otherwise. thx U_U CORRIGE: Uh.. I me myself can edit answers actually !  XD

Comment: @Campa good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 23):

`Ctrl + F8`, the default shortcut to change views, reduces the pain a bit.

Answer (score 9):

I filed a bug for this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327983

Comment: Duplicate of the 9-years-old bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46336 , although I think yours is better, more generic, and not tied to Java view

Comment: What we can do is vote for https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46336 , maybe this will make them really do something about this bug.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think it's possible to have eclipse switch back automatically but you can do it with the click of a button in the top-right of your window

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you would need to write eclipse plugin

[here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg32299.html) i found example how in plugin switch perspective

Answer (score 2):

As of 2015, this very basix UI woe is not addressed in Eclipse: the [official bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46336) is assigned (but not fixed).

Fortunately, [Sven Ramuschkat and Dirk Eismann](http://www.richinternet.de/blog/index9d72.html?entry=04B294D2-0413-3D17-6BA9F4FDF805B401) wrote a plugin for that: the [Perspective Switcher Plugin for Eclipse / Flash Builder](http://www.richinternet.de/blog/indexa36f.html?entry=1758AACF-910C-DE52-368E1421BEFDA19B)

> the Plugin will now automatically switch back from a Debug perspective to the previous non-Debug perspective as soon as the Debug session is terminated

It works on Eclipse Luna (and above)

### Installation

Download the [zip file](http://www.richinternet.de/blog/download/de.richinternet.plugins.perspectiveswitcher_0.1.1.zip) , uncompress and copy the jar file in your `eclipse/plugins` folder.

Once it's done, you will see a new `Preference` pane.

[image: pref]

Everything is configured for Eclipse to switch back to `Java` perspective if you have a `java` or `properties` file opened when the debugging session ends.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I use the `Java EE` prespective. After debug it switches to `Java` prespective and not `Java EE`. Also, with the plugin enabled I cannot even manually switch to `Java EE` as it changes it back to `Java` event when not debugging (Luna 4.4.2).