# Set Eclipse to automatically switch to Java perspective when terminating debug

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Eclipse, how do I change perspectives after terminating a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521442/in-eclipse-how-do-i-change-perspectives-after-terminating-a-process)

Having Eclipse automatically switch to debug perspective while debugging is a great feature - is the opposite available?  I'd like it to automatically return to Java perspective when terminating a debug session.  A keyboard shortcut to return to Java perspective could be help as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, `Ctrl-F8` is bound to switch between perspectives (but it can be rebound, if desired). Pressing it once will select the previous perspective.

Comment: On the mac that would be `Apple-F8`. I would also suggest updating the text to say that this is the default binding, since it could be changed.

Comment: This is ridiculous; Visual Studio offers this feature.

Comment: How does this answers the question? Why is this an acceptable answer? The question is about *automaticaly* switching perspectives and not using a keyboard shortcut. This should be a comment only.

Comment: @Odys Did you read the entire question? It ends with "A keyboard shortcut to return to Java perspective could be help as well."

Comment: in neon.2 at least, this does not switch perspectives. it just puts up a dialog

Comment: Well, it shows a list of possible perspectives to choose from, but you do not need to confirm anything, just select what perspective you want to switch to. And just pressing Ctrl-F8 will switch to the previous perspective.

Answer (score 2):

For the keyboard shortcut to return to Java perspective:

Window - Preferences - Keys

Then search for *perspectives*, you will find an entry like *Show perspective (Parameter: Java)*, bind to that the shortcut you'd like.