# Being in Debug View, and after program termination, switch back to Java View in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am looking for a way to come back to the standard Java View in Eclipse after the application I'm debugging is over.

Is it possible to accomplish that? That is the default behaviour in some other IDEs (Visual Studio, for instance) and I'd prefer to have it that way. It's so boring to have to go an manually switch the view again to the initial one :(

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't it get annoying when the app terminates unexpectedly and the GUI suddenly shuffles everything around?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Eclipse to automatically switch to Java perspective when terminating debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983398/set-eclipse-to-automatically-switch-to-java-perspective-when-terminating-debug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse is a generic platform where you can have a dozen type of different launch configurations, so a good and usable 'generic' implementation of this feature is not trivial.

However, there is an [open bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46336) for this feature, which has some activity recently so there is a chance that this feature will be included after Eclipse 3.7.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a plugin that does what you want. Here's the update site:

http://backtojava.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

I didn't categorize the feature, so when you look for it, unselect the "Group items by category" checkbox.

And here's the project on Eclipse Labs I made to host the source:

https://hg.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/backtojava

I haven't checked the Feature project in; just the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never seen such a feature. I also wouldn't consider such a feature desirable. Rare would be the occasion where I would be in debug mode for only a single run. Typically, the editing window provided in the debug mode is sufficient for any edits I would make during a debugging session.

Comment: My point is that while debugging I'm interested in the debug view, but after the application is over I have no interest in keeping it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Eclipse?  There are other Java IDEs, for example in Intellij IDEA you can set the debug window 'unpinned', so it hides when you click on the editor.  Personally I would find that behaviour annoying but it might work for you.

Comment: Short answer: yes, I have to use it.