# Eclipse automating perspective changing

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm using eclipse for some Java and Perl project, i've enabled under the menu : Preferences - Run/Debug , the option for automating passing to Debug perspective when debug start.

Is possible to automatically passing to the Java perspective when the debug terminate or when i terminate the debug ? Is there a way to set this option ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760967/being-in-debug-view-and-after-program-termination-switch-back-to-java-view-in-e

Comment: why don't you use shortcut keys?? `CTRL+F8` is the shortcut for perspective switching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, there is no such option I think. You'd have to implement it by yourself. I also suggest to use shortcut keys (CTRL-F8) until the [corresponding Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46336) is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you a plugin that does what you want. Here's the update site:

http://backtojava.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

I didn't categorize the feature, so when you look for it, unselect the "Group items by category" checkbox.

And here's the project on Eclipse Labs I made to host the source:

https://hg.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/backtojava

I haven't checked the Feature project in; just the plugin.