# Automatically changing Eclipse perspective when launching an application

Tags: eclipse

Is is possible to change Eclipse IDE perspective when I launch an application?

There are similar, though not identical questions around: 
[Eclipse automating perspective changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862898/eclipse-automating-perspective-changing) or [Being in Debug View, and after program termination, switch back to Java View in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760967/being-in-debug-view-and-after-program-termination-switch-back-to-java-view-in).

*Use-case:* having a single monitor here, I would like to have my **console** get much bigger while running an application (while still switching to *Debug* perspective if I am in debugging mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Doc [Changing the active perspective when launching](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9.htm)

> You can control which perspective becomes active when a program is launched and when it suspends. The setting is configurable for each launch configuration type, for each of the launch modes it supports.
>
> **To activate a particular perspective when a program is launched, do the following:**
>
> 1. Open the **Run/Debug -> Perspectives preference** page.
> 2. Select the Always option for the Open the associated perspective when launching preference. This will cause the perspective associated with a program to become active whenever it is launched.
>
> **To activate a particular perspective when a program is suspends, do the following:**
>
> 1. Open the **Run/Debug -> Perspectives preference** page.
> 2. Select the Always option for the Open the associated perspective when an application suspends preference.  This will cause the perspective associated with a program to become active whenever a program suspends.

---

See the following image for open `Run/Debug -> Perspectives preference`. This will be same for kepler also.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sumit: _Run/Debug -> Perspectives preference_ ? Which Eclipse version are you referring to, I don't have it here (_Luna_) .. ?

Comment: @Campa Open the Preferences (Window > Preferences or Eclipse > Preferences on Macs) select Run/Debug > Perspectives.

Comment: @Campa I updated the ans. This is not related to luna, this will work for you eclipse too. Which version of eclipse you are using?