# Ecplise IDE: Is there a way to automatically switch back in perspectives?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

I'm just wondering if there is a configuration to **automatically** switch between perspectives when one gets out of focus.
Example: I'm in the Scala Perspective and start debugging from there. Eclipse automatically switches to the Debugger Perspective as soon as I reach a breakpoint. But when my app terminates, Eclipse does not switch back to the Scala Perspective but stays in Debugger. I have to do it manually.
I already know about the hotkey F8, but that still requires some interaction.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984725/639520

Comment: @E-Riz : You are right, the question was asked but it was not answered regarding the "**automatically**" part.

Comment: The marked duplicate question's answer does explain that the answer is "no" and even explains (sort of) why. Some people don't like that answer, but it is THE answer, regardless.

Comment: @E-Riz: thx anyway