# Plugins installed on Eclipse not visible

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I install a plugin in Eclipse everything goes well. But after restarting the new plugin is not visible. I have tried it with different plugins, but they have all the same problem. The only place where I can see them is when I look at "What is already installed?".

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 12):

This issue and its solution is described in a [DZone article](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/problems-eclipse-36-helios) and at the [nWire blog](http://blog.zvikico.com/2010/08/eclipse-plugin-installation-and-windows-user-access-control.html).
It all boils down to these two options:

- Install Eclipse to a folder where your user has full rights ***or***
- [Start Eclipse as an administrator](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305780)

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo eclipse -clean;
```

`Help -->  Install software -->`  Re-install the plugins and software;

Explanation:
Eclipse is installed and 
the majority of programs are also installed initially with root privileges.

Typically 'Ownership' of hidden install folders like this belong to the 'Sudo' or Root user.  Therefore changes and installs to these hidden folders will not take.

Comment: Windows: *Run as administrator*

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried running [Eclipse with the -clean argument](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Eclipse_FAQs#I_have_just_installed_a_plug-in_but_I_do_not_see_any_indication_of_it_in_my_workspace._What_do_I_do.3F) ? You need to do this only once and not every time you start Eclipse, you it is recommended to do so after a plugin installation.

If that doesn't help, verify if you have privileges to write onto the features and plugins subdirectories. The plugin installation process requires the write privilege, but I've never seen a plugin installation succeed without one; still, it is worth checking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could be in a custom [perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521442/in-eclipse-how-do-i-change-perspectives-after-terminating-a-process) in which the plugin commands are not set to be visible (hence no menu, no view, ...). See [this question for more on perspectives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627914/how-to-add-perspectives-in-eclipse).

[image: Open perspective view]

Can you see your plugins in the `<eclipse>/plugins` and `<eclipse>/features` directories?
Can you check your "Error Log" view and see if there is any error message?
Can you see if the Preferences reference your plugins?

You can also try re-launching Eclipse with the `-clean` command line argument

Comment: It seems like they are not in the <eclipse>/plugins directory. Also they are not listed under Eclipse Installation Details -> Plugins, only under "Installed software". How can I solve this?

Comment: @Derk: then you need to monitor your Error Logs view during the *installation* phase and see if anything suspicious is reported there. What plugin are you trying to install? One you made or one you reference through an external update site?

Comment: I tried Subversive, Subclipse and some others, but there is no difference. I see nothing in the error log in the plugin development perspective. I try to install them via Help -> Install new software. Then everything goes well, but after Eclipse asks to restart nothing is visible

Comment: @Derk: could you try that on a fresh Eclipse installation? What Eclipse version are you using? And what package (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php)?

Comment: I already tried a fresh installation, but it didn't help. The version I'm using is the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. The windows 64 bit version from the development builds

Comment: @Derk I have the same problem now...did you solve this problem? if so how?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem one time where I was running eclipse with an old jre - it worked but plugins that needed jre6 didn't load. Do you have a recent jre in your path and as your java_home?

Comment: Thanks alot, that was as well my problem

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed a plugin which I no longer needed. Adding to @VonC , I found my plugins are under **/.eclipse/org.eclipse.plaform.xxxx/features**
and **/.eclipse/org.eclipse.plaform.xxxx/configurations folders.**

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and in my case Eclipse was starting up using an older version of Java. The Oozie plugin requires 1.8 Java version. Starting up Eclipse using the 1.8 version Java fixed it for me.