# disabling MercurialEclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-plugin

How do I disable MercurialEclipse? I don't really use it anymore and it causes startup delays, but I can't find any option to turn it off.

(note: this is Eclipse 3.4.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try and [**customize your current perspective**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697882/plugins-installed-on-eclipse-not-visible/2697896#2697896).
You would then un-select any command and shortcut related to that plugin.

Another solution would be to un-install the plugin (Help - About Eclipse - Installation details - first tab)

[image]

---

When looking at [**Eclipse 3.4** news and noteworthy](http://mirror.ousli.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/whatsnew3.4/eclipse-news-all.html), you could try and revert to a configuration where that plugin wasn't installed:

> The UI for performing installation and updates is completely new in 3.4. The new UI is accessed using `Help > Software Updates`.

[image]

Try the button "Revert configuration"

---

Or try:

**`Help -> Software Updates -> "Installed Software"`**: the old location for the first screenshot of this answer.

---

Note the [codeturner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193347/codeturner) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721600/disabling-mercurialeclipse/2721645#comment19945285_2721645):

> If you uninstall, you'll have to re-import each of these projects into your workspace to remove all MercurialEclipse settings.
>   Otherwise, Eclipse will throw errors in its error log

Comment: you're running 3.5, I think, and I am not

Comment: @Jason S: this should work in 3.4 even though those pages has been moved in 3.5 (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-all.html)

Comment: In the about box, I see Feature Details, Plugin Details, and Configuration Details. There is no uninstall button.

Comment: If you uninstall, you'll have to re-import each of these projects into your workspace to remove all MercurialEclipse settings.  Otherwise, Eclipse will throw errors in its error log.

Answer (score 7):

The best way is to disconnect your eclipse project from mercurial 
right click on your project
goto team -> disconnect from mercurial....

thats all

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem uninstalling the plugin/feature? You can do this under "About Eclipse SDK → Installation Details".

Comment: ?? I do not see such a feature

Comment: in the about box, I see Feature Details, Plugin Details, and Configuration Details

Answer (score 0):

I found how to uninstall in 3.4.2.

You need to do Help -> Software Updates... -> "Installed Software" tab, select the plugin, then click the "Uninstall..." button.

(Still, this is kind of extreme, and takes several minutes... it would be nice if there were just a way to temporarily enable/disable.)

Answer (score 0):

The other option would be to remove HG installation from your OS. So eclipse won't be able to start it.

Comment: Then Eclipse keeps complaining it doesn't find the hg executable. Bad solution.