# TeXLipse install on Juno not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, latex

I have tried to install the TeXLipse extension in Juno Eclipse, running on Ubuntu 12.04.

The installation goes off without a hitch however when I choose the project creation wizard TeXLipse is not there as an option. It is also not showing up in the Windows > Preference section of eclipse.

Has anyone else experienced this and have a suggestion on how to get this to work. I have googled around and other people have gotten it to work with Juno. I am just not sure what I am missing.

Thanks

**Edit: Solution**

I want to impart some details. I have the stock Eclipse install for Eclipse on Ubuntu. I then did an update where I simply replace the eclipse install located in `/usr/lib/eclipse`.
You can Google around for specifics.

To figure out what my system was doing I did two things.

1. Located in the `~/workspace/.metatdata` folder is a file called `.log`. At the terminal I ran `tail -f ~/workspace/.metatdata/.log` so that I could watch the log files for any errors as I did the installation.
2. I ran eclipse from the terminal `$> eclipse` to see any errors were produced.

My first error was that eclipse could not fine `~/.eclipse` file/directory when I ran eclipse. So I simply created this directory in my home folder and this error went away. I tried to install the plugin and I got a new error posted to the `.log` file:

```
!SESSION 2013-01-31 11:21:39.559 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2013-01-31 11:23:38.266
!MESSAGE An error occurred while committing the engine session for profile: epp.package.jee.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2013-01-31 11:23:38.266
!MESSAGE 
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2013-01-31 11:23:38.266
!MESSAGE Error saving manipulator.
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: **/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini** (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
at 

org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EclipseLauncherParser.save(EclipseLauncherParser.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxManipulatorImpl.save(EquinoxManipulatorImpl.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.LazyManipulator.save(LazyManipulator.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.EclipseTouchpoint.saveManipulator(EclipseTouchpoint.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.EclipseTouchpoint.commit(EclipseTouchpoint.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.EngineSession.commit(EngineSession.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningSession.performProvisioningPlan(ProvisioningSession.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProfileModificationJob.runModal(ProfileModificationJob.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

The installer wanted to update the `/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini`. I changed the permissions on this to write all (the alternative is to run eclipse as root which I didn't want to do).
I uninstalled the plugin and re-installed it and now it works as intended. I hope this helps someone else. **Don't forget to reverse the permissions after.**

Comment: I indeed have the same problem, with Texlipse and with other plugins, but am still looking for a solution.

Comment: I managed to fix my problem. It is as ingomueller.net said, it was a permissions issue. I have detailed my solution in my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse seems to need write permissions to the place where you installed it. How I see it, this leaves you with two options:

1. Install (i.e., extract) Eclipse to a folder you own, for example your home folder.
2. If you installed Eclipse to `/opt/eclipse` owned by root, you also have to install plugins as root.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697882/plugins-installed-on-eclipse-not-visible) describes the same problem under Windows. [This (German) website](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Eclipse) suggests option 2 from the above as solution.

Comment: I have not had a chance to try this yet, I ended up using a different product that is not as good to get by on till I could find a good answer. I had manually upgraded my Eclipse version for Ubuntu so I might have borked some of the permissions in doing that. I will check your solution and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for this tid bit. Will keep you posted.