# Eclipse Won't Load e(fx)clipse Plugin After Successful Installation

Tags: eclipse, efxclipse

I just installed e(fx)clipse (an JavaFX plugin for Eclipse) for Eclipse Mars, and even though I followed the install instructions to a T, there are no signs that it was ever installed; save for it being listed in Eclipse's installed plugins.

I followed [these](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/AddingE(fx)clipse_to_eclipse) instructions carefully, and managed to have it successfully install. The [next tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1) though says to use the wizard to create a new JavaFX project, but that option isn't available! If I type "JavaFX" (or any abbreviated form) into the search bar, nothing comes up. It also doesn't have any settings in the preferences which I don't think is right. Lastly, the main reason I installed the plugin was to use the JavaFX docs, but those aren't working either.

I already uninstalled the plugins, the Eclipse, then reinstalled them both, but that didn't help. I don't where to go from here given as far as Eclipse is concerned, it was installed properly, so I'm not getting any errors to work with.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697882/plugins-installed-on-eclipse-not-visible) post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out about the state of the plugin by opening the "Console"-View select the "Host OSGi-Console" (at the far right dropdown) and enter "ss org.eclipse.fx" this should list all e(fx)clipse bundles.

You can then post to https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/259/ asking for help. BTW there's also an All-In-One Download at http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html - it's not been updated to 4.5.1 but I'll try to get that done in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the plugin from Eclipse Marketplace. Try with a fresh copy of Eclipse.

Comment: Is there a difference between getting the plug in from the repository vs the marketplace?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But, it is an easy alternative to using the update site directly (and thus making mistakes "somewhere" in the process).