# How do I properly setup JavaFX for Eclipse Mars?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin

My Java specifications: JRE: 1.8_u60, JDK: 1.8_u60

JAVA_HOME is set-up correctly.

I´ve downloaded and installed the latest Eclipse Mars Java SDK (Eclipse Mars.1 / 4.5.1) from the official [Eclipse download page](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and used the installer.

I used the Eclipse update site from [e(fx)clipse](http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/2.0.0/site) to install the JavaFX IDE.

As described in the site´s tutorial I should now be able to create FX projects with File > New > Other > JavaFX ...

But unfortunatelly I don´t have any option to create an FX project. There is no sub-section called JavaFX.

How do I set up JFX for Eclipse Mars properly (if my setup does not work at all)? here is one more similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833136/eclipse-wont-load-efxclipse-plugin-after-successful-installation/32836014#32836014) asked.

Comment: I've replied with some details on the other thread you linked to

Comment: In case you run E(fx)clipse under Ubuntu 15.04 (or higher) this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34244308/2849346

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the installed plugin and try installing it through Marketplace.

Edit after the answer was accepted:
Just for clarification, it should also work in the way OP has tried it. Before one tries to troubleshoot why it's not working, it is very convenient to verify that the installation is not working from marketplace either.

Comment: thanks, that worked. running eclipse mars with fx now. i can separately select fx projects from new > other > ... now.

Answer (score 4):

Since JavaFX is [now on default classpath](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-January/005677.html), you do not need any extra plugin to create a JavaFX application. You can just create a simple Java Project in Eclispe and get started.

But, e(fx)clipse is recommended to install on Eclipse because of the [extra features](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html#about-tooling) it adds to the IDE.

I just finished installing the e(fx)clipse plugin on my Eclipse Mars to check if your scenario can be reproduced, but unfortunately after installing the plugin & restarting Eclipse, I can create JavaFX projects.

You can either try restarting Eclipse or re-install the plugin again.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32970189/2691625) in previous Question by tomsontom, you can check your status of  e(fx)clips bundles. Or you can use All-In-One [Download](http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html).