# Why is JavaFX is not included in OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu Wily (15.10)?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, javafx

I've downloaded OpenJDK 8 today via `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` and it seems like JavaFX is not included in it.

```
> java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

I've installed E(fx)clipse in latest Eclipse (Eclipse Mars) too, but I'm still getting message *javafx couldn't be resolved*.

Comment: @MWiesner , Ubuntu Mate 15.10 Beta 2. I've installed Oracle JDK now.

Answer (score 155):

According to the [packages list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/openjfx) in Ubuntu <strike>*Wily*</strike> <strike>Xenial</strike> Bionic there is a package named **openjfx**. This should be a candidate for what you're looking for:

> JavaFX/OpenJFX 8 - Rich client application platform for Java

You can install it via:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

It provides the [following JAR files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/openjfx/filelist) to the OpenJDK installation on Ubuntu systems:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/ant-javafx.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/javafx-mx.jar
```

If you want to have sources available, for example for debugging, you can additionally install:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx-source
```

Comment: which one do you import to use the the javafx functions?

Comment: @JürgenK. I usually let my IDE decide, but I guess `jfxrt.jar` is the one you are looking for.

Comment: For what it's worth, I suspect installing the `openjfx` package may only affect installed applications, rather than providing access in a dev environment.. I saw an error flash about missing "javafx" when running FileBot on Mint 18, which I resolved by installing this. From the dev side this would be (at most) a runtime dependency, which isn't generally installed directly into the main system. **Or** am I mistaken here..?

Comment: If you are using IDEA, make sure remove the currently selected JDK in Project Structure, SDK by clicking red minus button then re-add the JDK so JavaFx related files/classpath loaded by IDEA.

Comment: On Raspberry Pi I had to follow the instructions in this answer to avoid some missing library errors https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018995/2407742

Comment: works for me. However I've downloaded javafx unpacked tar.gz and copied manually.

Comment: Note that this will download the latest version of OpenJFX and there seem to be no way to install the older one, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjfx/+bug/1799946.

Comment: @MWiesner, your suggestion to import jfxrt.jar is contrary to what this says: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Using+an+IDE#UsinganIDE-JDK-8Only:Deletejfxrt.jar(ormoveittoadifferentdirectory) I have just done a clean install of ubuntu 18.4 and openjfx8 (held at version 8). It doesn' work for me in any case, so I am trying to see what I really need to do - why is there a difference between your suggestion and the article?

Comment: If it matters I checked the properties of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar` and it turns out it's a broken link, with link target showing as  `../../../../../../share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar` (copied exactly from the Properties) - could this be my problem? If so, where should it be pointed?

Answer (score 21):

I use ubuntu 16.04 and because I already had openJDK installed, this command have solved the problem. Don't forget that JavaFX is part of OpenJDK.

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

Comment: If it's part of it, why does it have to be installed separately?