# Running app in IDE stops working

Tags: codenameone

Last week I finished development on a test app and ran it successfully in all simulators.
Today I decided to look at publishing the app and used "Sent Android Build". Build status "Successful".
Then tried running jar from command line and got:

```
peter@PeteSuse:~> java -jar "/home/peter/NetBeansProjects/mobile-apps/pGame/dist/pGame.jar"
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1.run(Executor.java:84)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
```

So tried to run from GUI and got:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
    at com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory.createImplementation(ImplementationFactory.java:69)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.init(Display.java:566)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1.run(Executor.java:112)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
```

Java version:

```
peter@PeteSuse:~> java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.3.0) (suse-23.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

I am using Netbeans (new to this) on Suse Linux 42.1 64b.

Have I lost a library somewhere? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I fixed the problem by adding jfxrt.jar to the Libraries in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

[JFXPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) is in the [JavaFX library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#JFXST784).

See: [JavaFX and OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk) for info on why JavaFX is not available by default in your OpenJDK distribution.

1. If your linux distribution makes an open JavaFX package available (like ubuntu does: [Why is JavaFX is not included in OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu Wily (15.10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243982/why-is-javafx-is-not-included-in-openjdk-8-on-ubuntu-wily-15-10)), then you can use that.
2. Otherwise you can [build from source](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX) (for the adventurous yak shaver).
3. Or, easiest, is just to an [Oracle Java distribution](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html).

---

I don't know codenameone or have any idea how it works.  Possibly whatever it is, you could ask the creators to package their thing as a [self-contained application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html), so that it ships with a compatible Java runtime, which would (potentially) avoid issues such as you are encountering.  Not knowing codenameone, I don't know if that would make sense or not.

I also don't know the cause of your original `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as that looks internal to codenameone or your use of it.

---

With regards to NetBeans, you might need to [set the Java platform](https://joanpaon.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/how-to-change-netbeans-default-java-platform-2/) to one with JavaFX installed (in case you have multiple Java platforms installed on your machine).

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Codename One application in the simulator by pressing the play button in the IDE. It won't work for you from Command Line and shouldn't since the app shouldn't have a main() method.

You can execute the Codename One simulator from Command Line using:

```
java -jar JavaSE.jar:dist/MyApp.jar
```

Notice this assumes your project is the working directory.