# Gradle Compilation can't find tornadofx on Linux

Tags: gradle, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I am trying to compile a kotlin application with gradle.  The application uses tornadofx (kotlin version of javafx).

In `build.gradle`, I have:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.5.0'

    // Required for local unit tests (JUnit 4 framework)
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

In `MyApp.kt` I have:

```
import javafx.application.Application
import tornadofx.App
```

When I compile this project on Windows 10, either with `gradle clean build` or `.\gradlew clean build`, it compiles and works perfectly.

When I compile this project on Ubuntu Linux, I get a page of error messages, including:

```
...

e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class tornadofx.UIComponent, unresolved supertypes: javafx.event.EventTarget
    class tornadofx.App, unresolved supertypes: javafx.application.Application

...

e: /home/al/project/app/src/pcUi/MyApp.kt: (3, 8): Unresolved reference: javafx
e: /home/al/project/app/src/pcUi/MyApp.kt: (12, 5): Unresolved reference: Application

...
```

Although if I do this from a clean set-up, the gradle output also includes:

```
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/no/tornado/tornadofx/1.7.8/tornadofx-1.7.8.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/moshi/moshi/1.5.0/moshi-1.5.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/moshi/moshi-parent/1.5.0/moshi-parent-1.5.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/moshi/moshi-kotlin/1.5.0/moshi-kotlin-1.5.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/json/1.0.4/json-1.0.4.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/java/jvnet-parent/3/jvnet-parent-3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.1.3/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.1.3/kotlin-reflect-1.1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.13.0/okio-1.13.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okio/okio-parent/1.13.0/okio-parent-1.13.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.3/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.3/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/no/tornado/tornadofx/1.7.8/tornadofx-1.7.8.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/moshi/moshi/1.5.0/moshi-1.5.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/moshi/moshi-kotlin/1.5.0/moshi-kotlin-1.5.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.1.3/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.1.3.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.1.3/kotlin-reflect-1.1.3.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.13.0/okio-1.13.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.3/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.3.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.3/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.3.jar
```

This doesn't make sense to me as it's downloading the dependencies correctly (on Linux and Windows), but then only succeeding to compile on Windows and not Linux.  I haven't been able to figure out what's going on, so can anyone offer any suggestions for where to look?

Comment: Assuming you're using OpenJDK, JavaFX is not included by default as it is with Oracle's JDK, so you may need to install it or switch to Oracle.

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, it's as simple as `sudo apt-get install openjfx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the error message:

`e: /home/al/project/app/src/pcUi/MyApp.kt: (3, 8): Unresolved reference: javafx
e: /home/al/project/app/src/pcUi/MyApp.kt: (12, 5): Unresolved reference: Application`

It seems like you do not have your JDK set up correctly on Ubuntu. JavaFX is no longer a part of the OpenJDK, you have to install it manually: https://packages.qa.debian.org/o/openjfx.html .

Edit: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43301246/4697327 . You're probably using the Oracle JDK on Windows, which has JavaFX included.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  I think I'd been working on the misguided assumption that gradle was downloading everything (including javafx) that was necessary, but clearly it was just getting the tornadofx add-on bit.  Installing openjfx on Linux sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

To quickly re-include JavaFX in my project, I modified my `build.grade` file and let it sync.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}
```

Comment: I am on Mac and this worked for me. Thanks!