# Is openjfx megred in OpenJDK?

Tags: java, openjfx

I would like to know if openjfx is merged in OpenJDK, if not where can I find ppa link of openjfx?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this answer might be of use for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34244308/2849346

Answer (score 1):

OpenJFX and OpenJDK are two separate projects and therefore not merged.

As for a PPA, it depends on which distro you are using.  For Ubuntu check out this:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjfx