# Application working on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx, jar

I have a weird problem. I have a `.jar` file that I need to run but when I run it on my Windows PC it works but when I run it on my Ubuntu server it doesn't work. I've installed `default-jre` on the Ubuntu machine and when I run it by `java -jar {my name of file}` it says this:

> Error: Could not find or load main class {name of the class that is
>   missing} Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javafx/application/Application.

I've also installed openjfx and openjfx-source using apt-get install so:

```
apt-get install openjfx
apt-get install openjfx-source
```

My Windows java version: 
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

My Ubuntu java version:
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2, mixed mode)

Comment: What does `java -version` display on the Linux machine?   (Add this to your question!)

Comment: Yes, I think. What else it would be?

Comment: @StephenC java -version says this: openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2, mixed mode)

Comment: OpenJDK does not include javafx: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34243982

Comment: I've installed openjfx and  openjfx-source manually.

Comment: You could check whether they're in the right folder, or otherwise add them to the classpath manually

Comment: What if is in the right folder?

Comment: You could try adding the jars to the classpath either way, but beyond that I don't know.

Comment: Please add Linux _and_ Windows Java version to he question and how / where you installed fx

Comment: Ubuntu only has openjfx packages for openjfx 8, so you'll have to use Java 8 for them to be applicable. If your need Java 9 or later, your best bet is to install Oracle's JRE and set it as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found why it didn't work. The application was build to run on Java 8 and I've installed Java 11 on it. Now it works perfectly with Java 8.