# Javafx and linked files

Tags: java

I am working on Intellij IDE and when I started to learn how to write code in javafx style I faced the problem that IDE do not resolve any javafx packages and so on(Watch the screenshot). I assume that library of this IDE just do not include this packages, if not could you tell what the problem is and how can I solve it? I have Ubuntu OS. Thanks a lot.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search returned this thread:
[Why is JavaFX is not included in OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu Wily (15.10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243982/why-is-javafx-is-not-included-in-openjdk-8-on-ubuntu-wily-15-10)
Should anwser your question.