# PyDev 5.5 does not appeas in Eclipse 4.6.2 and java 1.8

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Hello everyone I am trying to use PyDev and I fullfil PyDev requirements I mean I have installed eclipse 4.6.2 and java 1.8.0_121-b13.

But PyDev does not appear in prespective view.

[image]

Does someone know what coud be happend or how I could resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just foud the soulucion, I think I got desperated so fast, but here is the solucion [Plugins installed on Eclipse not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697882/plugins-installed-on-eclipse-not-visible/3419064#3419064)

I just have to run eclipse as root with clean argument

```
sudo eclipse -clean
```

Well just like the answer explains :D