# Eclipse Oxygen | Installed Drools plugin doesn't show in perspective

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, drools, eclipse-oxygen

I have installed ***Eclipse Oxygen*** . I tried installing **Drools 7.3.0** in my eclipse.
When i try to install i get below scenario.
Prior to this i had installed and used drools in Eclipse Luna.

[image]

I checked the installed software tab in the below path:
**Help-->About Eclipse-->Installation Details**
I can see the Drools plugins installed . Sharing the image from my eclipse.

[image]

When i checked on goole , i saw the similar problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697882/plugins-installed-on-eclipse-not-visible). I checked and tried the options mentioned to no use. I cannot run it as admin , however i have all rights for the folder in which it is installed.I cannot see Drools in the perspective as a result of which i cannot create a Drools project.

Is it because of any bug in Oxygen which i am unaware of ? Or am i a missing a thing.
I have Java 8 on my system.

Comment: Look in the log file in the .metadata folder of your workspace on disk.  Well-written plugins will often log missing pre-reqs or conflicts that prevent perspectives and views from being seen.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look as if you have the plugins installed.

You have to download the zip file from `drools.org/download/download.html`given under the heading **Drools and jBPM tools**. This expands into a directory `droolsjbpm-tools-distribution-x.y.z.Final` with a subdirectory `./binaries//org.drools.updatesite`. Follow the instructions in `./ReadMeDroolsJbpmTools.txt`. This should install 7 plugins

```
org.drools.eclipse
org.guvnor.eclipse.webdav
org.guvnor.tools
org.jboss.tools.runtime.drools.detector
org.jbpm.eclipse
org.kie.eclipse
org.kie.eclipse.navigator
```