# How can one show the gdb traces in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gdb

I am new to Eclipse Helios and wonder how can one show the gdb traces in eclipse.

Comment: May be in `Window->show view->other...`

Comment: I can see there a window called "trace control", but whenever I run in debug mode, using the standard process launche or DSF/GDB, no info appears in that window

Answer (score 3):

problem solved, under console, we can select the different views; gdb, gdb traces, and so on

Comment: For anyone using Eclipse Neon and newer, this has changed since Eclipse Neon CDT 9.2 release. GDB traces option does not appear by default in the Console view. It must be first enabled in the Preferences as in the answer by @metdos. This change is documented: https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn92

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences/(C/C++)/Debug/GDB, in *General Behavior* part, mark the next checkbox:

`Show the GDB traces consoles with character limit`

Answer (score 0):

Install the necessary additional Eclipse plugins as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760094/2110769), then Run>Debug. The debug windows will open. When your program crashes, you will find the backtrace in the "Debug" window