# GDB in Eclipse CDT crashes: Error in `gdb': free(): invalid next size (fast):

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

If I start my debugger within Eclipse to debug my C program, it shows me a gdb error and crashes. I can run the debugger without problems from the command line. This is a problem within gdb. May Eclipse make use of some unstable gdb commands ??

```
GNU gdb 7.7.1 Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later  This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details. This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu". Type "show configuration" for configuration details. For bug reporting instructions, please see: . Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at: . For help, type "help". Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word". [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled] Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
*** Error in `gdb': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000031fc290 ***
```

```
762,450 2-gdb-version
762,450 ~"GNU gdb 7.7.1\n"
762,457 ~"Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"
762,457 ~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later \nThis is fre\
e software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitt\
ed by law.  Type \"show copying\"\nand \"show warranty\" for details.\n"
762,458 ~"This GDB was configured as \"x86_64-linux-gnu\".\nType \"show configuration\" for configur\
ation details."
762,458 ~"\nFor bug reporting instructions, please see:\n"
762,458 ~".\n"
762,458 ~"Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:\n.\n"
762,458 ~"For help, type \"help\".\n"
762,458 ~"Type \"apropos word\" to search for commands related to \"word\".\n"
762,458 2^done
762,459 (gdb) 
762,462 3-environment-cd /home/wolle/workspace/simple
762,462 3^done
762,462 (gdb) 
762,463 4-gdb-set breakpoint pending on
762,463 4^done
762,463 (gdb) 
762,465 5-gdb-set detach-on-fork on
762,466 5^done
762,466 (gdb) 
762,467 6-enable-pretty-printing
762,467 6^done
762,467 (gdb) 
762,468 7-gdb-set python print-stack none
762,468 7^done
762,468 (gdb) 
762,469 8-gdb-set print object on
762,470 8^done
762,470 (gdb) 
762,471 9-gdb-set print sevenbit-strings on
762,472 9^done
762,472 (gdb) 
762,473 10-gdb-set host-charset UTF-8
762,473 10^done
762,473 (gdb) 
762,474 11-gdb-set target-charset UTF-8
762,474 11^done
762,474 (gdb) 
762,478 12-gdb-set target-wide-charset UTF-32
762,478 12^done
762,478 (gdb) 
762,479 13-gdb-set dprintf-style call
762,480 13^done
762,480 (gdb) 
762,481 14source .gdbinit
762,481 &"source .gdbinit\n"
762,481 &".gdbinit: No such file or directory.\n"
762,481 14^error,msg=".gdbinit: No such file or directory."
762,481 (gdb) 
762,483 15-gdb-set target-async off
762,483 15^done
762,483 (gdb) 
762,484 16-gdb-set auto-solib-add on
762,484 16^done
762,485 (gdb) 
762,488 17-file-exec-and-symbols --thread-group i1 /home/wolle/workspace/simple/D\
ebug/simple
762,493 17^done
762,493 (gdb) 
762,500 18-gdb-show --thread-group i1 language
762,500 18^done,value="auto"
762,500 (gdb) 
762,502 19-gdb-set --thread-group i1 language c
762,502 19^done
762,502 (gdb) 
762,503 20-interpreter-exec --thread-group i1 console "p/x (char)-1"
762,503 ~"$1 = 0xff\n"
762,503 20^done
762,503 (gdb) 
762,504 21-list-thread-groups
762,505 21^done,groups=[{id="i1",type="process",executable="/home/wolle/workspace\
/simple/Debug/simple"}]
762,505 (gdb) 
762,506 22-data-evaluate-expression --thread-group i1 "sizeof (void*)"
762,506 22^done,value="8"
762,506 (gdb) 
762,511 23-gdb-set --thread-group i1 language auto
762,512 23^done
762,512 (gdb) 
762,513 24-interpreter-exec --thread-group i1 console "show endian"
762,513 ~"The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)\n"
762,513 24^done
762,513 (gdb) 
762,520 25-break-insert -t -f main
762,520 25^done,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="del",enabled="y",addr="0x000000000040053c",\
func="main",file="../src/main.c",fullname="/home/wolle/workspace/simple/src/main.\
c",line="14",thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",original-location="main"}
762,521 (gdb) 
762,522 26-inferior-tty-set --thread-group i1 /dev/pts/28
762,522 26^done
762,522 (gdb) 
762,535 27-exec-run --thread-group i1
762,537 =thread-group-started,id="i1",pid="14755"
762,537 =thread-created,id="1",group-id="i1"
762,538 27^running
762,538 *running,thread-id="all"
762,538 (gdb) 
762,538 28-list-thread-groups --available
762,548 =library-loaded,id="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",target-name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",h\
ost-name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
762,563 =library-loaded,id="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6",target-name="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc\
.so.6",host-name="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
762,721 =breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="del",enabled="y",addr="0x00000\
0000040053c",func="main",file="../src/main.c",fullname="/home/wolle/workspace/sim\
ple/src/main.c",line="14",thread-groups=["i1"],times="1",original-location="main"}
762,723 *stopped,reason="breakpoint-hit",disp="del",bkptno="1",frame={addr="0x000000000040053c",func\
="main",args=[{name="argc",value="1"},{name="argv",value="0x7fffffffdfc8"}],file="../src/main.c",ful\
lname="/home/wolle/workspace/simple/src/main.c",line="14"},thread-id="1",stopped-\
threads="all",core="1"
762,725 =breakpoint-deleted,id="1"
762,725 (gdb)
```

How to get the mi/gdb traces see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260157/how-can-one-show-the-gdb-traces-in-eclipse)

The problem may be the loaded thread library. Can I configure to turn this off in Eclipse ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not quite enough detail to figure out what is going on for me. Have you reduced this to a HelloWorld size program, i.e. does gdb + cdt always crash? Can you provide the MI communications (there is another console in Eclipse that has them)?

Comment: Yes, the gdb inside cdt also crashes for a simple HelloWorld program.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting of my computer, all things went well again. I really don't know what the problem was.