# debug c with eclipse and get error

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

I'm using Eclipse for C programming as I've installed the C/C++ plug-ins from the 'Help' menu but when I go to debug I get the error below. I've downloaded and installed GDB for mac and if I type 'gdb' in bash I go into the app. How do I get eclipse to recognise gdb?

"Error while launching command: gdb --version"

EDIT: I just need to know where the location of the gdb files are on the mac.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758794/how-do-i-use-gdb-in-eclipse-for-c-c-debugging

Comment: I've read that already and didn't help. Thanks for your reply