# String args display

Tags: java, string, args

I understand that `String args[]` inside the public static void main line,
is used to store arguments from the command line.

So is it possible to print what's inside `args[]`?

I wrote code that prints from `args[0]` what I entered in the scanner.

I know I can print what's inside "a" scanner but is it possible to print what's inside "b" ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lesson1 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

        String b = args[0];

        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you pass any argument? 
How do you run program?

Comment: try to print `b` instead of `a`...

Comment: May be this  
`System.out.println(b);`

Comment: sorry i ment to print "b"

Comment: Are you passing arguments in? How are you running the program? Can you provide more details about why it "doesn't work"? (like what error you're getting)

Comment: This is the contents of your program...how are you _running_ the program? Through Eclipse? From the command line?

Comment: i'm running from eclipse . and got this error message : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at apples.main(apples.java:9)

Comment: This is what you need to do to pass arguments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646719/eclipse-command-line-arguments

Comment: ok i think my class name is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the entire contents of args like so:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
```

Comment: i putted this line you wrote instead of : System.out.println(a); . and i only see [] int the console

Comment: This means `args` is empty. You aren't passing any arguments to the program.

Comment: so user input from scanner is not an argument ?

Comment: No, it isn't. `args` are the command line arguments. The input from `Scanner` is just user input.

Comment: how do i pass an argument in eclipse ?

Comment: Don't forget to try googling the answer. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646719/eclipse-command-line-arguments