# Exception- in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

```
public class Sum {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int x,y,s; 
    x=Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
    y=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    s=x+y;
   System.out.println("sum  "  +s);

} 
}
```

i wanted to print the sum of two number using command line agument ..but it showing some error :-Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0....

Comment: did you pass anything to args

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the command-line arguments:

```
java Sum 0 1
```

---

It's also recommended to check length in this case:

```
int x,y,s;
if(args.length>=2){
  x=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  y=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  s=x+y;
  System.out.println("sum  "  +s);
}
```

---

And considering the intent of the program, you might want to loop the `args[]` array directly, and sum ***all*** numbers instead of just the first 2:

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
  total = total + Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}
System.out.println("Total: " + total);
```

Command-line: `java Sum 1 2 3 4 5` results in `Total: 15`

Answer (score 0):

When you run this from the commandline, you need to pass in your values for x and y:

```
java Sum 4 5
```

If you are running this from eclipse, you need to set it up to pass these arguments in every time you hit the green "run" button.

[Eclipse command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646719/eclipse-command-line-arguments)

If you don't pass anything in, then the array "args" will be empty. Then you try and access the first element in the array, but since it is empty, this throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.