# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error message from the console

Tags: java, exception

When I run this code, it comes up with the Exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 thefirstone.Distance.main(Distance.java:18)
```

I'm copying this from a tutorial and it says if you receive the error message I received, it's because "you didn't provide enough numbers." Not sure what they're talking about.

The code:

```
  public class Distance {
 private java.awt.Point point0, point1;

 public Distance(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
   point0 = new java.awt.Point(x0, y0);
   point1 = new java.awt.Point(x1, y1);
 }

 public void printDistance() {
  System.out.println("Distance between " + point0 + " and " + point1
                  + " is " + point0.distance(point1));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Distance dist = new Distance(
           intValue(args[0]), intValue(args[1]),
           intValue(args[2]), intValue(args[3]));
  dist.printDistance();
}

private static int intValue(String data) {
  return Integer.parseInt(data);
}
}
```

Comment: You can find the answer just typing your question in google. This is a duplicate question as well. Next time, search before you ask please.

Comment: you need to set up your run configuration. What IDE are you using, or are you just using the command line?

Comment: @flkes I'm using Eclipse

Comment: To populate `String[] args` you need to add in program arguments. Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19648592/3280538 answer. For your program type in 4 numbers separated by spaces

Answer (score 0):

Exception `ArrayOutOfBoundException` can only came due to this line of code

```
 Distance dist = new Distance(
           intValue(args[0]), intValue(args[1]),
           intValue(args[2]), intValue(args[3]));
```

> Please Verify the number of argument passed at the time of execution. if it is less than 4 in numbers then only this `Exception` might you got.