# Java - Passing arguments to the Main method

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-arguments

I'm just a beginner to write programs in Java. How to pass the arguments `(Array of strings)` to the main method? I'm using Eclipse as an IDE

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (args[0].equals("-h"))
        System.out.print("Hello,");
    else if (args[0].equals("-g"))
        System.out.print("Goodbye,");

    // print the other command-line arguments
    for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++)
        System.out.print(" " + args[i]);

    System.out.println("!");
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't access args[0] unless you know for sure you have at least one element in the args array.

Comment: m a beginner too and just curious why is args getting checked if its equals to "-h" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Run > Run Configurations > Java Application > Arguments > Program
>   arguments

[image: Arguments]
[image: Result]

---

Also, make sure your code works when no arguments are passed, **don't just directly pick values from array**.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
            if (args[0].equals("-h"))
                System.out.print("Hello,");
            else if (args[0].equals("-g"))
                System.out.print("Goodbye,");

            // print the other command-line arguments
            for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++)
                System.out.print(" " + args[i]);

        } else{
            System.out.print("No Arguments passed");
        }
        System.out.println("!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments in Run Configurations -> Java Application -> Arguments -> Program arguments

Link :- http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/eclipseCommLineArgs.html

Comment: That website looks like it hasn't been updated since 1998.

Comment: It still provides the basic overview which is used to pass the arguments. You can also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646719/eclipse-command-line-arguments/19648592

Answer (score 0):

right click | run as | open Run Dialog |（x）=Arguments

then put you args