# Activate Java perspective from Debug perspective in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

When I debug an android application it activate Debug perspective from Java perspective; but it doesn't switch back to Java perspective when I terminate the application using red terminate button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [In Eclipse, how do I change perspectives after terminating a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521442/in-eclipse-how-do-i-change-perspectives-after-terminating-a-process)

Short answer: there's no way eclipse can decide when to switch back.

Comment: Yes duplicated; do you know what to do next?

Comment: I can see two option, but neither of them are the solution for your problem. You can use Ctrl-F8 to switch between perspectives, or in the settings you can set the debug perspective to open in a new window. These are not solutions, but can make your life a little bit easier.